# Background thread still listening on TCP port after service stopped

Tags: c#, windows, service, task-parallel-library, tcplistener

I'm writing a C# service (.NET 4.0) which listens on a TCP port. I start the TcpListener on a background thread (using Task Parallel Library) so the service is not unresponsive to Windows. I also use TPL whenever a client connects, as each client will do some database work and I don't want to block other clients.

I install and uninstall the service using InstallUtil.exe on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. Whenever I stop the service and uninstall it, using netstat -abo I can see the port is still being listened to by the [System] process. It has a PID, however I can't see a process with this PID in Task Manager or tasklist, nor can I kill it with taskkill. It just says process not found, but it's always there when I run netstat -abo. If I try to start the service again using the same port, I get a socket exception:

```
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
Stacktrace:
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
```

I'm guessing my background threads are still hanging around after I stop the service, but I have no idea how to kill them now, and how to prevent this from happening. Here is what I hope is the relevant code (deleted exception handling and logging for easier reading):

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
        {
            private static TCPServer server = null;

            protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
                server = new TCPServer();
            }

            protected override void OnStop()
            {
                if (server != null)
                {
                    server.StopServer();
                }
            }
        }

    class TCPServer
        {
            public static TcpListener listener = null;
            private static Task listenerTask = null;
            private static List<Task> clientTasks = new List<Task>();

            public TCPServer()
            {
                    listenerTask = new Task(() => StartServer());
                    listenerTask.Start();
            }

            public void StopServer()
            {
                foreach(Task task in clientTasks)
                {
                    task.Dispose();
                }

                    listenerTask.Dispose();

                    if (listener != null)
                    {
                        listener.Stop();
                        listener = null;
                    }
            }

            private void StartServer()
            {
                    Int32 port = 51987;
                    IPAddress localAddr = GetLocalIP();

                    listener = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
                    listener.Start();

                    while (listener != null)
                    {
                        if (listener.Pending())
                        {
                            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                            Task task = new Task((obj) => ProcessClient(obj), client);
                            task.Start();
                            clientTasks.Add(task);
                        }
                    }
            }

            private void ProcessClient(object obj)
            {
                    using (TcpClient client = obj as TcpClient)
                    {

                    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[2048];
                    String data = null;

                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                    int i;

                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    }

                    // do some stuff with data
                    // If an exception is thrown here, the rogue thread issue happens when I stop the service. 
                    // Otherwise, everything is good - I stop the service and no rogue thread, I can reuse the listener port. 
                    }
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:** 
Updated the code with suggested changes. I've also discovered that this rogue thread issue only seems to occur if an exception is thrown in one of my client threads. If everything runs ok, there is no rogue thread when I stop the service.

Comment: There's no Dispose function on TcpListener.

Comment: I'd like to recommend two things: do not reuse names for different purposes: server and task are the ones I think of. The other issue is, I'd recommend keeping a reference to task, both occurrences. This may also help in your issue.

Comment: I see Task has Dispose, so I kept a reference to Task and put task.Dispose in my StopServer function. However I get the following error: A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Stop" method, in this case, means stoping the current connection and start listening to a new one so make sure your client is closed properly so that a new connection is not created.

> The Stop method also closes the underlying Socket and creates a new
> Socket for the TcpListener. If you set any properties on the
> underlying Socket prior to calling the Stop method, those properties
> will not carry over to the new Socket.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.stop(v=vs.110).aspx#

Moreover, make sure you use `using` with the client

```
using(TcpClient client = obj as TcpClient){//DO SOMETHING}
```

Comment: I think your answer has pointed me somewhat in the right direction, in particular "make sure your client is closed properly so that a new connection is not created." What's the best way to stop the listener without creating a new socket?

Comment: Calling "client.Close();" before shutting down the server